# Why is multiplication O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Hi I am learning about Big-O and was wondering why multiplication is O(n^2). I think I know why but I am just not sure. Is it because of how long multiplication work? I know that addition is Linear time O(n) and if we do binary multiplication we would first multiply all the bits and shift it. After we finish shifting and multiplying all the bits we would do the addition. So I am guessing the recursive call of the multiplication is O(n) and the addition of the result will be O(n). So combing the two run time will give us O(n^2). Is that right or am I on the wrong track?
Edit:
So I guess what I am asking is why is the grade school multiplication is O(n^2)

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

First of all, multiplying *what*? Are you multiplying, matrices? Are you multiplying, polynomials? Are you multiplying, integers? Are you multiplying, floating point numbers? Are you multiplying, integers modulo a prime?

Assuming you are talking about multiplication of integers as you learned in grade school --

The (naive) grade school algorithm is `O(n^2)` because when you multiply an `n`-digit number by an `m` digit number using it, you end up with essentially a sum of `m` shifted copies of the `n` digit number which you then have to add up. It involves writing down approximately an `n+m` by `m` grid of digits, and then adding up all those numbers, so you need about `n^2` time and space over all in that method.

However, there are many better multiplication methods known, like Russian Peasant multiplication, and for extremely large numbers, the fastest methods achieve roughly `O(n log n)` time. These methods are based on the fast fourier transform, and are quite sophisticated.

No one knows how to prove that multiplication cannot be done in `O(n)` time, it's in theory possible that it can be.

So when you ask

> Why is multiplication O(n^2)?

the answer is, its not, and what exactly it is, we don't know, its somewhere between `O(n)` and `O(n log n)`. Only certain algorithms for it are `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Upvoting not only because this is the correct answer, but also because you wrote it in 9 minutes. That must be some kind of record. But I think the answer would be better if it had some links to more material about the subject.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put that I am multiplying m-bit number x and n-bit number y. If this is the case would my first line of thinking would be correct since I was thinking about the long multiplication?

Comment: @RonnieGarcia: So when you say this part "I know that addition is Linear time O(n) and if we do binary multiplication we would first multiply all the bits and shift it. After we finish shifting and multiplying all the bits we would do the addition." that sounds to me like Russian Peasant multiplication. But when you say this "So I am guessing the recursive call of the multiplication is O(n) and the addition of the result will be O(n). " I'm not sure what the recursive call is. So it might be better to write actual pseudocode?

Comment: @Juan Lopes: "That must be some kind of record" Hehe, all in a day's work :) So I'm not sure what links to add, I mean I could add links to wikipedia or something but it feels a bit worthless. If you want references for these algorithms, its probably better to refer to some textbook or some papers even I guess? But that's a lot of work. I think the OP only cares about gradeschool algorithm maybe or something, not sure.

Comment: Just simple grade school multiplication right now. What I meant about the recursion is that if you multiple a number like 241 by 12, wouldn't you have to first multiple 2 to every number in 241 and than shift it and multiple 1 to every number in 241. Like the number 2 and 1 is being recursive in the number 241. I don't know if I explain that well or not.

Comment: Your answer is fine as it is. There is another multiplication algorithm which multiplies in O(n log n) and is not so complex as it does not use fast fourier transform (etc.). It just uses a simple divide and conquer strategy. The algorithm is called `karatsuba multiplication`

Comment: @vish4071: While Karatsuba (Анато́лий Алексе́евич Карацу́ба) is right (he pondered the same question even when Kolmogorov (Андрей Николаевич Колмогоров) proposed quadratic complexity), "loglinear" for [Karatsuba's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) is _wrong_.

Comment: The "Russian Peasant" algorithm is O(n^2). Doubling and halving requires O(n) steps and each summing requires n-bit wide addition.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: I thought that it was still more efficient for other reasons, like that it uses less space than the naive method. It might be better to rewrite that part of the answer though so its less confusing, I agree that the way I wrote it seems to imply that Peasant multiplication is better than `O(n^2)`...

Comment: I beleieve that "Convolution" is the algorithim related to FFT that is used for multiplying arrays, vectors and large integers, etc.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Convolution is definitely used for multiplying polynomials in some contexts. The algorithm I was referring to in the post, for integers, is the Schonage-Strassen algorithm, which is more like a series of convolutions than a single convolution iiuc